# How to get the biggest sum in 2D array in O(n)?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I need to calculate the biggest sum possible in 2D array, but the code must be in the efficiency of O(n).
n is the number of numbers we have in the array.

The array is like stairs, and the user just needs to enter N numbers. We don't need to check if it's a valid number.

The numbers will be shown in array like this:

1

2   3

4   5    6

7   8    9    10

In every row there is one more number.

You need to get the biggest sum path possible, starting from first or last row.
At each iteration you can move only one step down, or one step diagonally down and left / down and right.

That means that if you start from the first row, you can go to 2 or 3. Let's say you go for 2; now you can go only for 4 or 5. If you choose 5, you can go just to 7 or 8 or 9. Or if you want you can go to 1 > 3 > 6 > 8. But you cannot go to 1 > 2 > 6 > 10 because 2 isn't connected with 6.

You also can select only one number in a row. You can't go 1 > 2 > 3 > 6 > 8 > 9 > 10 or something like that.

We can also change the value of a cell, but the path must be the same. That means that I can change, for example, 9 to be 50, but it won't be good because it was not a good path in the original array. (The max sum path in this array 1 > 3 > 6 > 10, so i cant go to different cells)

My problem is that I need this code to run with efficiency of O(n).

I tried to go from the last line and check every valid path that it can go, I tried to go all ways for the biggest number in each possibility. The first one isn't O(n) efficiency and the second one can get the wrong answer.

I also tried to do it from the first row and to scan and compare all the steps, but again it's not O(n) efficiency.

**Just to make sure, I'm not requesting anyone to write the code for me, just to help me figure out what is the best way to calculate it.**

BTW, saw few comments and wanted to add that at the end, I need to print the maximum path sum, but not the path itself.

Comment: At first glance this appears to be an exercise in which you would build out a tree of paths.  At each node of the tree is the sum for reaching to that node.  Then at the end you would have terminal nodes that you would then use to see the sum for each of the paths.

Comment: It's not clear why 9 > 50 is not a good path. Please edit that into your question.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, I think the 9 to 50 has to do with changing a cell value rather than a path.  Any cell value changes have to be such that they do not change the highest sum path by making a path that includes the changed cell a higher sum than the original highest sum path.  So I suppose one may go through the matrix and add some value to each element of the matrix for instance.  Not sure why you would do cell value changes unless this constraint is to prevent someone from using the matrix elements to hold path sums?

Comment: Right, but the posted restrictions on changing cell values include "good path". This is confusing.

Comment: Richard - I think you right on that, and I tried to do it from top to bottom, but it wasn't O(n). Need to figure out a way to work with it to O(n).

Nathan - Thank you for the edit suggestion. I wrote it again. hope that now its good.

Just saw richads comment - he's right, that's what I meant.

Comment: Are there constraints for the numbers? I.e. could the next row be `1 1 1 1 1` or `1 2 1 2 1` as well?

Comment: No, there is not. The next row can be any positive numbers you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can determine the maximum sum from the bottom up. For example, the two bottom rows are:

```
  4   5   6
 / \ / \ / \
7   8   9  10
```

Now accumulate the maximum possible sum to the second but last row:

```
 12  14  16
 / \ / \ / \
7   8   9  10
```

Foe example, the maximum you can make from either 7 or 8 at node 4 is 12. Continue this, but with the max-sum values, to the top:

```
     20
     / \
   16  19
   / \ / \
 12  14  16
 / \ / \ / \
7   8   9  10
```

The top node now has the maximum possible sum: 1 + 3 + 6 + 10 == 20. This approach will destroy the original data (because it overwrites it with the max-sums) and it will not give you the path, only the value of the maximum sum.

Here, the triangular array looks like a tree, but you don't really build a tree: The links can easily be described by their positions.

**Edit**: I now realise that this doesn't quite solve your question, because it omits the possible step to the left, but the principle still is good: Accumulate the maximum possible sub-sums from the bottom up, except that you need to consider the three values below, not only two. (I'm a bit loth to redraw the ASCII trees. :-)

**Edit II**: As @rpattiso points out, you have the optimum path in the accumulated tree by following the maximum sum of the three possible child nodes from the top.

**Edit III**: When you treat the matrix as stairs and consider three children of each node, the graph becomes:

```
  20
   | \
  16  19
   | X | \
  12  14  16
   | X | X | \
   7   8   9  10
```

Here, the `X` mean two crossing paths. Note that the first column is a special case, because nodes in this column have only two children.

If `m` is the number of rows and `n = m*(m + 1)/2` is the number of cells and if your array is represented by a two-dimensional C-style array `a[row][col]`, then your max-sum algorithm is:

```
int row = m - 1;

while (row--) {        
    a[row][0] += max(a[row + 1][0], a[row + 1][1]);

    for (int col = 1; col < row + 1; col++) {
        int a1 = a[row + 1][col - 1];
        int a2 = a[row + 1][col];
        int a3 = a[row + 1][col + 1];

        a[row][col] += max(a1, a2, a3);
    }
}
```

You maximum sum is the value of `a[0][0]`.

Comment: The longest path is still encoded in the new tree, start from the top and pick the branch with the largest value going down, if they are equal, there are multiple solutions. And when following this path you can subtract the adjacent sums to get back the original values on the path.

Comment: @rpattiso: Good point. I didn't see that, although now that you mention it, it is obvious.

Comment: Thanks.
Just edited my post - it doesnt matter what is the path, just the sum of it, so your idea is good... but can is it gives me O(n) ?
How can I check if 7+4 is bigger than 8+4 without using a loop inside a loop ?

Because I will get an array with unknown numbers...

Comment: You visit every node except the bottom row exactly once. For each visit, you must find the maximum of the three child nodes, which is an O(1) operation, so the complexity should be O(n).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but i still dont get it well.
I dont know how to write the graph so nicely like you so i will link to a photo of it.

If i have this array:

http://i.imgur.com/UKK4UpZ.png

and I'm starting with 7. 
did "IF" to see whats bigger, 7+4 or 8+4. saw that 8+4.
after that, i have to check what is bigger, 7+5 or 8+5. saw that 8+5, and now i change the value of the cell from 5 to 13.
later on i will need to check 9 with that cell, but its not 5 anymore, so i will get a wrong answer...

I see how it works in the tree you posted, but i just can't figure it in stairs.

Comment: @MOehm - If i have this array:
http://i.imgur.com/MY0yIGb.png

the tree algoritham won't find the real maximum path.
how i can resolve this? your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @MOehm - yes it is. but with tree i get 45... This is the tree i got after the calculations.
http://i.imgur.com/ZuiGTBj.png

Comment: Have you seen my last edit to the answer? There I explain how to adapt the tree solution to your problem. With the code I posted, I get 49. You are probably missing the 9 that is to the left of the 15.

Comment: @MOehm - I'm sorry, i guess i missed that edit. Thank you very much for your help!! I really appreciate it!!

Comment: Yeah, I kind of made the edit silently without announcing it. Glad you find the asnwer useful.

Answer (score 0):

one option would be to prepare a directed graph by putting relevant edges, add a sink node and run Dijkstra from 1 to sink node. not going to be linear though (sink node is the one connected to 7 8 9 10)
another solution might be dynamic programming, bottom-up (described in first answer) or top-down